# Getting Node -1 disconnected error after subscribing to kafka topic in camel code

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume from a kafka topic and simply print the body in logs.
the code works when I try to connect to a local kafka topic on localhost but I get error when I try to connect to dev1 kafka topic.

In the logs I see after my code subscribes to the topic then I get these errors
Node -1 disconnected
Canceled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 21 due to node  -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 131ms ...)
Bootstrap broker (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

this is my code:

```
from("kafka:mytopic?brokers=xxxx:9094&groupId=xxxx&autoOffsetReset=latest&keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer&specificAvroReader=true&valueDeserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer&schemaRegistryURL=xxxx:8081")
.log("Message is : ${body}");
```

the xxxx is a valid url which is confidential.
the camel version is 3.2.0
I am getting the same error when I try to connect to kafka through core java as well

Comment: Without seeing your kafka server properties, it's hard to help. How do we know port 9094, or the address you've hidden is correct? Have you tried using just Kafka CLI commands to consume some data since regular Java consumer isn't working either? You seem to be missing auth, which is typically if you're not connecting to the default port